# How to Convert SQL query consisting 'not in' into LINQ?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

SELECT distinct [Taskid] FROM[Dbimg].[dbo].[table1] where Taskid not in (select Taskid from[Dbimg].[dbo].[table1] where ValidationFlag is null)

Please help to convert above sql query in linq c#.

Comment: Where db is the linq data context

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
db.table1.Where(x => !db.table1.Where(y => y.ValidationFlag == null).Select(z => z.Taskid).Contains(x.TaskId))
         .Select(x => x.TaskId).Distinct();
```

But in your case you can also modify the above LINQ as below as you are using the same table

```
db.table1.Where(y => y.ValidationFlag != null).Select(z => z.Taskid).Distinct();
```